# Refresh of grouped data not rendered even if server response is correct

Tags: javascript, python, datatables

I load data from database and I see this in my table

[image]

This is an example of JSON data of my database, I have 4 columns, table is called `user`

```
[
    {
        "badge": "ebooks",
        "extra": "test",
        "id": "Il Piccolo #14 settembre 2023",
        "username": "https://t.me/laso...../686/196499"
    },
    {
        "badge": "ebooks",
        "extra": "test",
        "id": "Il Piccolo #16 settembre 2023",
        "username": "https://t.me/laso...../686/196500"
    }
]
```

To view data in DataTables in NON-GROUPED MODE I used this python code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, send_file
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import request, jsonify
from sqlalchemy import text
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:/Users/Peter/Desktop/tabella_server_side/dati2.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    badge = db.Column(db.String(80))
    extra = db.Column(db.String(80)) 

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
def search_data():
    try:
        search_term = request.args.get('search[value]')
        start = int(request.args.get('start', 0))
        length = int(request.args.get('length', 5))
        order_column = int(request.args.get('order[0][column]'))
        order_dir = request.args.get('order[0][dir]')

        columns = ['id', 'username', 'badge', 'extra']

        if 0 <= order_column < len(columns):
            order_by = columns[order_column]

            if order_dir == 'desc':
                order_by = f'{order_by} DESC'
        else:
            order_by = 'id'

        query = User.query
        if search_term:
            query = query.filter(
                (User.id.ilike(f'%{search_term}%')) |
                (User.username.ilike(f'%{search_term}%')) |
                (User.badge.ilike(f'%{search_term}%')) |
                (User.extra.ilike(f'%{search_term}%'))
            )
            total_records = query.count()
            query = query.order_by(text(order_by)).offset(start).limit(length)
        else:
            total_records = User.query.count()
            query = query.order_by(text(order_by)).offset(start).limit(length)

        users = query.all()

        data = [{'id': user.id, 'username': user.username, 'badge': user.badge, 'extra': user.extra} for user in users]

        response = {
            'recordsTotal': total_records,
            'recordsFiltered': total_records,
            'data': data
        }

        return jsonify(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return jsonify([]), 500
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and this javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var lengthParam = parseInt(urlParams.get('length'));
    var startParam = parseInt(urlParams.get('start'));
    if (!isNaN(startParam) && startParam >= 0) {
        dataTable.page(parseInt(startParam / lengthParam)).draw();
    }

    var dataTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: '/search',
            data: function (d) {
                d.searchTerm = $('#userTable_filter input').val();
                d.length = d.length || lengthParam;
                d.page = d.start / d.length;
                d.start = urlParams.get('start') || d.start;
            }
        },
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        rowGroup: {
            dataSrc: 'id'
        },
        lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 100, 500],

        "columns": [
            {data: null},
            {data: 'id'},
            {data: 'username'},
            {data: null}
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0, 3],
                "visible": true,
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

I'm trying to group data in this way

[image]

but I can't do it. I add a button called "Raggruppa" -  I implement this python function

```
@app.route('/raggruppa', methods=['POST'])
def raggruppa_data():
    try:
        data = request.json
        print("Data received from the client:", data)

        grouped_data = {}

        for riga in data:
            id_, username = riga['id'], riga['username']
            mese, anno = trova_mese_anno(id_)

            if mese and anno:
                mese_anno = f"{mese.capitalize()} {anno}"  # Formatta il mese e l'anno
                if mese_anno not in grouped_data:
                    grouped_data[mese_anno] = {'id': mese_anno, 'username': ''}
                grouped_data[mese_anno]['username'] += username + '<br>'

        print("Grouped data:", grouped_data)

        response = list(grouped_data.values())
        print("Answer:", response)
        return jsonify(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error processing your request:", e)
        return jsonify([]), 500
```

and this javascript click event to "Raggruppa" button

```
$('#raggruppaButton').click(function() {
    console.log("Pulsante 'Raggruppa' premuto");

    var data = dataTable.rows().data().toArray(); // Ottieni i dati dalla DataTable

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        url: '/raggruppa',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('Risposta dal server:', response);
        
            // Update the data in the DataTable
            console.log('Number of rows before update:', dataTable.rows().count());
        
            dataTable.clear(); // Removes all rows
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var row = response[i];
                dataTable.row.add({
                    'id': row.id,
                    'username': row.username
                }).draw();
            }
        
            console.log('Number of rows after update:', dataTable.rows().count());
        },


        error: function(error) {
            console.error('Errore durante la richiesta:', error);
        }
    });
});
```

Problem is about DataTables grouping rendering because instead of seeing ONE single grouped row I continue to see TWO ungrouped rows
This is strange because I see a correct response from the server regarding the data format. This is Console LOG from Browser

```
Button 'Raggruppa' clicked
script.js:60 Response from the server: [{…}]0: id: "Settembre 2023"username: "https://t.me/lasoffittadownloads/686/196499<br>https://t.me/lasoffittadownloads/686/196500<br>"[[Prototype]]: Objectlength: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
script.js:63 Number of rows before update: 2
script.js:74 Number of rows after update: 1
```